# Match N lines between char pattern, move N lines to be inline with char pattern

Tags: regex, sed

I am parsing a wikipedia table. The table contains data as follows

```
Tonga
0
Trinidad and Tobago
10
14
24
Tunisia
10
6
16
Turkey
12
14.5
26.5
```

I would like to have a regex (executable in the terminal, preferably sed or similar) that moves an arbitrary number N lines of numbers to the above A-Z country name

The expected output is:

```
Tonga,0
Trinidad and Tobago,10,14,24
Tunisia,10,6,16
Turkey,12,26.5
```

I have not come close, here are my best efforts. Your wisdown is appreciated

`perl -pe 's/^[0-9]*$/\n,/g'`

Produces

```
,
Trinidad and Tobago

,

,

,
Tunisia

,

,

,
Turkey

,
14.5
26.5
```

This is incorrect because I am replacing WITH `\n` and need to replace `\n` WITH something else. Unfortunately, I do not know if it's possible to match `\n` with sed/perl

I tried `tr`, but again I don't know how to maintain my match on the output. It replaces all chars with

`tr 'A-z\n' ','`

Produces
`,,,,,,0,,,,,,,,, ,,, ,,,,,,,10,14,24,,,,,,,,,10,6,16,,,,,,,,12,14.5,26.5,`

Comment: Have you attempted anything?

Comment: I tried matching the integers and replacing `\n` with `,` but my solution is very incorrect. I also tried a similar approach with perl to no avail... yet

Comment: @Goldfish  Show your code you have tried with in your question please. Check [mcve].

Comment: @Tiw I have updated with 2 examples I tried, neither are correct or close IMO

Comment: @Goldfish It's okay if it's not correct, if it's correct you probably won't even ask here. Just that it's important and polite to show your own efforts here, otherwise it seems just a request to let others do your job, to abuse the goodness of the answers here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=","}/^[a-zA-Z]+/ && val{print val;val=""} {val=val?val OFS $0:$0} END{if(val){print val}}'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:***

```
awk '
BEGIN{                      ##Starting BEGIN section here.
  OFS=","                   ##Setting output field seprator as comma here.
}
/^[a-zA-Z]+/ && val{        ##Checking condition if a line starts with alphabet and variable val is not null.
  print val                 ##Printing variable val here.
  val=""
}
{
  val=(val?val OFS:"")$0    ##Creating variable val and concatenating its value to its own for each line value.
}
END{                        ##Starting END block for this awk code.
  if(val){                  ##Checking if val is NOT NULL.
    print val               ##Then printing val here.
  }
}'  Input_file              ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: That works perfectly, could you please explain your answer for myself and the community? @RavinderSingh13

Answer (score 5):

```
$ awk '{printf "%s%s", (/^[0-9]/ ? "," : s), $0; s=ORS} END{print ""}' file
Tonga,0
Trinidad and Tobago,10,14,24
Tunisia,10,6,16
Turkey,12,14.5,26.5
```

Answer (score 2):

Another `awk` solution:

```
awk '/[a-zA-Z]/{if(FNR>1)print "";printf "%s",$0} $0+0==$0{printf ",%s",$0} END{print ""}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

And a `sed` solution:

```
sed -n -e '/[a-zA-Z]/{' -e 'x;/./s/\n/,/gp;x;h;}' -e '/^[0-9][0-9.]*$/H;${' -e 'x;/./s/\n/,/gp;}' file
```

Idea is to save each parts into hold space, and later switch out and replace `\n` with `,`s and print.

Answer (score 0):

by perl 5, your data in 'table';

```
$  perl -lpe 'BEGIN{undef $/} s/\n(?!$)/,/g; s/(?<=\d),([a-z])/\n$1/ig' table
```

or

```
$ perl -lpe 'BEGIN{undef $/} s/\n/,/g; s/([a-z ]+(,[\d.]+)*),/$1\n/ig' table
```